# Jetpack Compose – LazyColumn not recomposing

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-flow

My LazyColumn is not recomposing but the value is getting updated.

If I scroll down the list and scroll back up I see correct values for the UI

MainActivity

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            MyTheme {
                MyApp()
            }
        }
    }
}

// Start building your app here!
@Composable
fun MyApp(vm: PuppyListViewModel =  viewModel()) {
    val puppers by vm.pups.collectAsState(emptyList())
    Surface(color = MaterialTheme.colors.background) {
        Column {
            Toolbar()
            LazyColumn {
                items(puppers) { pup ->  PuppyUI(pup, vm::seeDetails, vm::togglePuppyAdoption) }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The ViewModel

```kotlin
class PuppyListViewModel : ViewModel() {

    val pups = PuppyRepo.getPuppies().onEach {
        println("FlowEmitted: $it")
    }

    fun togglePuppyAdoption(puppy: Puppy) = viewModelScope.launch {
        PuppyRepo.toggleAdoption(puppy.id)
    }

    fun seeDetails(puppy: Puppy) {
        println("seeDetails $puppy")
    }
}
```

The model

```kotlin
internal var IDS = 0L

data class Puppy (
    val name: String,
    val tagline: String = "",
    val race: String,
    @DrawableRes val image: Int,
    var adopted: Boolean = false,
    val id: Long = ++IDS,
)
```

The repository

```kotlin
object PuppyRepo {
    private val changeFlow = MutableStateFlow(0)
    private val pups: List<Puppy>

    private val puppyImages = listOf(
        R.drawable._1,
        R.drawable._2,
        R.drawable._3,
        R.drawable._4,
        R.drawable._5,
        R.drawable._6,
        R.drawable._7,
        R.drawable._8,
        R.drawable._9,
        R.drawable._10,
        R.drawable._11,
        R.drawable._12,
        R.drawable._13,
        R.drawable._14,
        R.drawable._15,
        R.drawable._16,
        R.drawable._17,
        R.drawable._18,
        R.drawable._19,
    )


    private val puppyNames = listOf(
        "Gordie",
        "Alice",
        "Belle",
        "Olivia",
        "Bubba",
        "Pandora",
        "Bailey",
        "Nala",
        "Rosco",
        "Butch",
        "Matilda",
        "Molly",
        "Piper",
        "Kelsey",
        "Rufus",
        "Duke",
        "Ozzy"
    )

    private val puppyTags = listOf(
        "doggo",
        "doge",
        "special dogo",
        "wrinkler",
        "corgo",
        "shoob",
        "puggo",
        "pupper",
        "small dogo",
        "big ol dogo",
        "woofer",
        "floofer",
        "yapper",
        "pupper",
        "good-boye",
        "grizlord",
        "snip-snap dogo"
    )

    private val puppyBreeds = listOf(
        "Labrador Retriever",
        "German Shepard",
        "Golden Retriever",
        "French Bulldog",
        "Bulldog",
        "Beagle",
        "Poodle",
        "Rottweiler",
        "German Shorthaired Pointer",
        "Yorkshire Terrier",
        "Boxer"
    )

    init {
        pups = puppyImages.map { image ->
            val name = puppyNames.random()
            val tagline = puppyTags.random()
            val breed = puppyBreeds.random()
            Puppy(name, tagline, breed, image)
        }
    }

    @OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
    fun getPuppies() = changeFlow.flatMapLatest { flowOf(pups) }

    fun getPuppy(puppyId: Long) = flow {
        emit(pups.find { it.id == puppyId })
    }


    suspend fun toggleAdoption(puppyId: Long): Boolean {
        val found = getPuppy(puppyId).first()?.toggleAdoption()?.let { true } ?: false
        if (found) {
            // Trigger a new emission for those that are consuming a Flow from getPuppies
            changeFlow.value = changeFlow.value + 1
        }
        return found
    }


    private fun Puppy.toggleAdoption() {
        adopted = !adopted
    }

}
```

The `Flow` pups is producing updated values as you can see in my logcat

[image: Logcat]

I've put print statements on my composables and they are not getting re-composed after the flow emits a new value.

## Edit.

Lookslike Compose compares the references of the objects and since those didn't change, recomposition didn't happen even if flows were emitting new values (a bug on Compose perhaps?)

Changed the `toggle` functionality to re-create the instances of the elements of the list like the following and now is working.

**Note:** I've made `Puppy.adopted` a `val` instead of `var`

```kotlin
suspend fun toggleAdoption(puppyId: Long): Boolean {
    var found = false
    pups = pups.map {
        val isThePuppy = it.id == puppyId
        found = found || isThePuppy
        if(isThePuppy) it.copy(adopted = !it.adopted) else it.copy()
    }
    if (found) {
        // Trigger a new emission for those that are consuming a Flow from getPuppies
        changeFlow.value = changeFlow.value + 1
    }
    return found
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> The `Flow` pups is producing updated values as you can see in my logcat

Not exactly.

The `Flow` is emitting the same `List` of the same `Puppy` objects. I believe that Compose sees that the `List` is the same `List` object as before and assumes that there are no changes.

My suggested changes:

- Make `Puppy` be an immutable `data` class (i.e., no `var` properties)
- Get rid of `changeFlow` and have `getPuppies()` return a stable `MutableStateFlow<List<Puppy>>` (or make that just be a public property)
- In `toggleAdoption()`, create a fresh list of `Puppy` objects and use that to update the `MutableStateFlow<List<Puppy>>`:

```kotlin
    suspend fun toggleAdoption(puppyId: Long) {
        val current = puppies.value // assumes that puppies is a MutableSharedFlow<List<Puppy>>

        val replacement = current.map { if (it.id == puppyId) it.copy(adopted = !it.adopted) else it }

        puppies.value = replacement
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare, I also thought about the idea of the actual objects _still_ being the same ones but with modified properties. On the `flatMapLatest` I've tried to re-create the list by creating a new `MutableList`, filling it with the old objects and then emitting it through the flow. So the `List` reference can't be the issue. I'll try recreating the entire list (object by object by doing pup.copy) after toggling the adopted flag.

Comment: And it worked... Seems that deep down in Compose's runtime they are checking equality of references rather than calling `equalsTo`? See my last edit of code

Comment: @SomerandomITboy: It is supposed to use `==`, which is why I guessed the `List` was the problem. Personally, I almost never use `var` on a `data class`, so I do not know quite why Compose was not detecting that change.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me.

```kotlin
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel

class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {
    var selectables: List<Selectable> by mutableStateOf(List(100) { Selectable(name = "$it") })
        private set

    fun onTapped(tappedItem: Selectable) {
        val index = selectables.indexOf(tappedItem)
        selectables = selectables.toMutableList().also {
            it[index] = tappedItem.copy(selected = !tappedItem.selected)
        }
    }
}

data class Selectable(
    val name: String,
    var selected: Boolean = false,
)
```

The key parts are:

1. Re-assigning the list rather than modifying it in-place (e.g. making `selectables` a `MutableList` and performing `selectables[index] = tappedItem.copy(selected = !tappedItem.selected)` wouldn't work)
2. Re-assigning the selected item rather than modifying it in-place, e.g. the following wouldn't work

```kotlin
selectables = selectables.toMutableList().also {
    it[index].selected = !tappedItem.selected
}
```

Note that you don't *have* to make your data class immutable, however, making it immutable will enforce that you have to make a copy of the element in order to update it.